# Accessing -willDisplayCell method of moreNavigationController's UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit

After setting the backgroundView of `UITableView` in moreNavigationController like so...

```
UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView *)tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;
[moreTableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
```

...the cells of that `UITableView` changed their `backgroundColor` from white to clear (transparent). I've tried setting it back to white with the following lines of code...

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in [moreTableView visibleCells]) {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

...but unfortunately this does not work, so I guess the only solution would be to set that backgroundColor in the `-willDisplayCell:` method. Can anyone tell me how to access that method? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom cell then the back ground colour of the cell can be set in a subclass of `UITabeViewCell`, otherwise you should try to add this logic to the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of the UITableView's datasource.

What you are doing in your loop will only effect the visible cells, since they will be reused and if the background is being set to clear dynamically then you'll always have your background overridden.

Comment: It's not a custom cell, the table view it generated automatically by UITabBarController. I'm accessing it in the -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: Are you using storyboards? I think you should try to set the background colour in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method inside your datasource (probably the tableview controller itself).

Comment: Yes, I'm using storyboards, but as far as I know, there's no way of accessing that UIMoreListController's tableView in Interface Builder.

Comment: So what you need to do is create your own subclass of UITableViewController and in storyboard, change the class of the tableview to your own class. Then you know storyboard will load your class, and now you have the code of your controller where all the datasource stuff could happen.